# Les hommes qui se sont aimés et se sont succédés ?

Tags: grammaire, accord, verbes-pronominaux

Our teacher said the following sentence is not correct but I can not figure out what is wrong with it

> Les hommes qui se sont aimés et se sont succédés

Comment: What do you want to say ? What is the context ? This sentence alone is weird, it has to be followed by something...

Comment: As given correctly by @Begueradj , “se sont succédé” should not end in “S” as it does in your example. I think your teacher is trying to determine how well you know the rules/exceptions of gender/plural agreement of past participles (L’accord du participe passé) [found here](https://frangram.wordpress.com/docs/accord-du-participe-passe/), especially when used with reflexive verbs (see the 4th bolded section, which even contains an example using the verb “se succéder” [the past participle of which, according to my trusty “Le Robert-Micro” is always/invariably “succédé,” with no ‘s’ or ‘e’]).

Comment: I hope they did not work in a sucette business empire, those hommes.you are technically not supposed to mix business and leisure.

Comment: @PapaPoule > Correct me if I'm wrong, but reflexive (se succéder) or not (succéder), this verb is always intransitive, no ?

Comment: @LaurentS.I literally "don't know what I was thinking" when I wrote that comment (literally in the sense that "I can't remember what I was thinking!). I probably was just excited that I'd found something on the "S-or-No S-on-succédé" issue,including an example nearly identical (except for the order & for using "haïS" instead of "aiméS") to the one in question ("Les hommes qui se sont succédé se sont souvent haïs. [On succède à quelqu’un mais on hait quelqu’un]"). 6768 calls it "transitif indirect," but I don't know enough about such things to say whether you calling it "intransitive" is wrong.

Answer (score 8):

There's one single error in your sentence: The issue is actually with the last verb *se succéder* which is [*transitif indirect*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitivit%C3%A9_%28grammaire%29#Verbes_transitifs) and in its *[forme pronominale](http://www.maxicours.com/soutien-scolaire/francais/3e/13293.html)*.

As you can read from [this source](http://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/du/verbe/se_succeder.php),  we should write:

> ils se sont succédé

So  the right form of  your sentence is:

> Les hommes qui se sont aimés et se sont succédé

Answer (score 3):

*Succéder à*, donc complément d'objet indirect, donc pas d'accord.

Answer (score 2):

You don't see the lack of clarity in "the men that loved each other and succeeded each other" what kind of succession? where does the phrase end? The meaning is not clear, as it uses common vague words to describe particular facts and situations.

Also the phrase is not finished.

Comment: The sentence may lack context, but it's complete and correct as such, with the exception of that '"s" in "succédés"

Comment: The phrase has a noun, some verbs, and then stops, like "that cats who played and jumped" "les enfants qui ont joué et couru" ... It can be a spoken reply in answer to the context, but it can't be a complete phrase in most litteral circumstances. In lacking context, it is not complete.

Comment: First of all I missed that earlier but "succedé" is not related to succeeding or success. Then about the lack of context, it doesn't make a sentence "not correct" (cfr the question) or "not complete". A lot of very correct sentences (from a grammatical and spelling perspective) are meaningless or worse have several meaning without a context. I understand your point, but in the context of a French lesson it seems perfectly normal to use short sentences and exclude context. You could for example ask what is wrong with "Les enfants se sont envolé", and the answer is not that "children can't fly".

Comment: succession and succession are the same word in English and Erench. Succeeding and succéder also. "Les enfants QUI se sont envolés" he uses qui, not "les enfants se sont envolé" his phrase is "The men WHO liked and succeeded one another".

Comment: But would a teacher focus on sentence construction before verb agreement? Com.mon sense?

Comment: I get your [& Random's](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/16652/#comment31095_16652) point.that "the phrase is not finished" (& that verb agreement is not the only error), but I think the Teacher wanted this "missing-something" error to be found **and fixed**, NOT by "adding something" but rather by simply OMITTING the "et" to give "Les hommes qui se sont aimés se sont [aussi/souvent] succédé" (Men who liked each another [also/often] succeeded each other) (in line with the example [under the 4th bolded section **here**](https://frangram.wordpress.com/docs/accord-du-participe-passe/).